# Hide or show an input when a checkbox is checked or unchecked in JSP file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, checkbox

Can anyone explain me why this piece of code does not work in Eclipse. I tried to compile the code on this site http://jsfiddle.net and it's working.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var checkbox = $('#checker'); 
        var dependent = $('#day_number');
        if (checkbox.attr('checked') !== undefined){
           dependent.show();
        } else {
            dependent.hide();
        }

        checkbox.change(function(e){
           dependent.toggle(); 
        });
    }); 
    </script>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checker"><br>
    <input type="text" id="day_number">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: This is my second question,  how do I include jQuery in Eclipse

Comment: Result from the site http://jsfiddle.net/Y39Bu/92/

Comment: I included jquery(instaled jsdt-jquery) but still not working I can not figure out where I was wrong